# How can I build a search that searches all the site collection under certain managed path?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search, 2013

I have created a WildCard managed path named `departments`, and then under this managed path I have created five “Publishing site- enterprise Wiki” site collections.

Now, by default, each of the enterprise site collection will have a Search functionality to search all the Pages content, attachments etc.

But I want to allow users to either search a specific Site collection or to search all the site collectiosn under the specific managed path. How can this be done?

Comment: I'd say you should setup some additional Search Scopes in which you configure which index should be searched through when chosen.

Comment: can you explain more your answers please...

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the Site Search box in 2013 is to search the site first and then when the user clicks the link to "Search Everything" that are taken to the global search center configured in the SSA. If you want an intermediate step where they only search the site collections under the Departments managed path there are a few approaches you can take.

You can make the process easier by creating Result Source for the departments managed path. Use a query like `Path:http://mycompany/departments/*`.

You could then add a search vertical to the search center for searching department content and direct the search query to use the Result Source you created above.

You could go one step further by creating a Query Rule that detects a user query for the Action Term "Department" and create a result block of results from the Departments Result Source.